# datastax session hangs with high volume parallel queries

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax

**Big Picture.**

The datastax session hangs when processing 2000 queries in parallel.

**Parallel Queries**

I am using Alpakka which wraps the Datastax Cassandra Driver. I'm using the Scala Play framework.

To do a row count on big data, it has to be done by partition. I use the following code to count the rows for each partition:

```
val futureList: ListBuffer[Future[Any]] = new ListBuffer[Future[Any]]
  val acc: mutable.HashMap[String, Long] = new mutable.HashMap[String, Long]()
  targets.isDefined match {
    case true =>
      targets.get.foreach {
        e =>
          val cq: CassandraQueries = new CassandraQueries()
          Logger.info("targets collected so far: "+acc.size)
          Logger.info("Calling count for "+e._1)


          futureList += cq.futureQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM " + keyspaceName + ".\"sparseData\" where label = " + e._2 + ";", sparseRowCountResult(acc, e._1), 120000)
      }

      val results = Future.sequence(futureList.toList)
```

In one of my keyspaces, I have 2000 partitions, hence 2000 queries in parallel.

**Query Results**

The query is processed by Alpakka/Datastax and returns a `Future[Seq[Row]].`

```
Logger.info("furtureQuery: session closed -> "+ session.isClosed)
    val stmt = new SimpleStatement(query).setFetchSize(200).setReadTimeoutMillis(readTimeoutMillis)
    val sb: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
    val source = CassandraSource(stmt)
    source.runWith(Sink.seq).onComplete {
      case Success(f) => out(Some(f), None)

      case Failure(e) =>
        Logger.error("simpleQuery failed with " + e.getMessage)
        out(None, Some(e.getMessage))

    }
```

**Exception and Hang**
After around 1000 queries, I get the following error. After this, nothing returns from the Session. Neither `Success` nor `Failure` occur.

> akka.ConfigurationException: Logger specified in config can't be
>   loaded [akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger] due to
>   [akka.event.Logging$LoggerInitializationException: Logger
>   log1-Logging$DefaultLogger did not respond with LoggerInitialized,
>   sent instead [TIMEOUT]]

**Question**

I am sure I can extend the timeout for the logging. But this is a symptom, not the real problem.

***How do I either:***

- configure Session connections to allow for 2000 parallel requests?

or

- constrain Future.sequence to the known number of possible requests?

***Also***

- How can I programmatically recover from such a Sessiion hang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase number of in-flight requests per connection by specifying the pooling options when creating a Cluster instance, like this:

```
PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
poolingOptions.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 10240);

Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .withContactPoints("127.0.0.1")
    .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
    .build();
```

But you still need to handle `BusyPoolException` in your code, because when using asynchronous requests, it's still easy to overload one particular connection.

More information is in [driver's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/).

Answer (score 1):

Rather firing 2000 queries perform a range query. Make use of cluster objects metatdata, get token range and calculate the token of the keys. Then, batch your queries that falls under the same range in one range query.